# Duplicate Vue component instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How i can duplicate a vue component instance after mount with new dom ?

I trying to code for a template builder and i want to duplicate some blocks.

Like duplicate function of [this site](http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor-3-5/index.php?demo=ZDb963RlP20upHwL7kicgaEQInxsUMze)

Answer (score 0):

The example the show is not dom duplication since left comp is just a button and right comp handle other events.

Why duplicate after mount? You can duplicate components declaration in your code.

This is a valid template like your example:

```
<div>
    <my-component style="width:10%" :data="data"/>
    <my-component style="width:90%" :data="data"/>
</div>
```

Any change in data will be seen in both instances since they "watch" the same data.

Comment: i want duplicate with all changes

Comment: Sure, With Vue.JS, components are view on your data (store and/or props). You can off course clone a component in the code, then changes in one component will be seen in the other.